# Django Admin Extended View

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have built out a Django voting application. The models are pretty simple.
I have a category , an entry , and participant model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Entry(models.Model):
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant)

    def __unicode__(self):
        output = 'Entry For {0} in Category {1}'.format(self.participant, self.category)
        return output
```

Pretty straightforward. You can add a category an entry and a participant using the default django admin models. This works really well.

Now the question:

In the admin, I want user to click a button and is presented with the listing of all winners for all the categories in the db. I have an idea on how to implement this,  where I basically want a user to submit a form in the admin interface. I know the admin interface is implemented via the way all djanog apps are MVC style. But I don't know where I can extend because the adminBaseModel / adminModel acts like a models and view controllers, and url-confs at the same time. It's seems difficult to rewire alot of the internets there.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Just want to simply implement my own view that merely extends the admin view with my own context and method calls.

I hope that was clear. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: How a bout ordering your EntryAdmin by votes ?
You'll get all entries by the highest votes found......